# sonar-3.5.1 deploying project on sonar server but code not showing

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have upgraded my sonar version from sonar-3.2 to sonar-3.5.1 and upgraded sonar-runner from sonar-runner-1.1 to sonar-runner-2.2.2, now when i am deploying project on newly installed sonar 3.5.1 it run successfully and showing ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, it also show project name on sonar server when i use localhost:9000 on browser but code is not showing there, no violations are coming etc.
i am using sonar in two ways and both results the same. Two ways are:
1. using sonar standalone through sonar runner from cmd.
2. integrating sonar with Jenkins(1.515) and using maven(3.0.4)

when i do sonar analysis on sonar 3.2 everything is working fine in both of the above cases but problem comes only when i use sonar 3.5.1.
Can anybody help me out on this issue??
Please suggest what would be the possible way to overcome this issue..
your revert will be appreciable.. Thanks in advance!!

Please refer below for logs

[image]

and sonar dashboard

[image]

Comment: Could you attach to this thread the analysis log of one of your project and the screenshot of this project dashboard when using Sonar 3.5.1 ?

Comment: Freddy, please see attached screenshot of sonar project analysis logs and sonar dashboard.

Comment: What do you have in the extensions/plugins directory ? Indeed looks like most java plugins are missing.

Comment: following plugins are existing in plugins directory:sonar-web-plugin-1.1,
sonar-jira-plugin-1.0,
sonar-ldap-plugin-1.2.1,
sonar-pdfreport-plugin-1.3,
sonar-quality-index-plugin-1.1.3,
sonar-technicaldebt-plugin-1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

So I do confirm that the Sonar Java plugins have been deleted from the extensions/plugins directory and that's why you don't get any measures/violations when analysing a java project. Here is the link to download version 1.2 of the Sonar Java plugin ecosystem : http://docs.codehaus.org/download/attachments/230396085/JavaEcosystem-1.2.zip. You just have to decompress this archive, place all jar(s) in the extensions/plugins directory and relaunch the Sonar server.

Comment: thanks Freddy it works.. but I would like to know that when I was using sonar till sonar-version-3.2, I was not at all required to place sonar java plugin ecosystem in extensions/plugin directory for analyzing a project. please let me know is it the requirement from sonar-version-3.5??

Comment: Indeed Shekhar as the Sonar Java plugins are no more part of the Sonar platform core since Sonar 3.4 (see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-3934)